# Is $F_p^{l}[t]$ is a UFD

Tags: unique-factorization-domains

I'm stuck here.

Let $F_{p}$ be a finite filed. Is  $F_{p^{l}}[t]$ a Unique factorization Domain.

Can anyone explain? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I presume $F_{p^l}$ denotes the finite field of order $q^l$.

The polynomial ring $k[t]$ is a UFD for **any** field $k$.
The proof is via the Euclidean algorithm for polynomials.